# Texcolor of Textview not being applied

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, colors

How is everything?

So, as the question says, i have two textviews in my fragment that has this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="projeto1.com.recyclerviewexample.BlankFragment"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutSquareWord"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutPrimaryWord"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ola_word"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/bluish_dark"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/secondaryWord"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_word"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textColor="@color/bluish"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/primaryWord"
    android:textSize="140sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i load the app on my device (Nexus 5), it doesn't show the color i specified, in other hand, it shows the `primaryWord` with black border and white color, and the `secondaryWord` with white border and black color.

Strange, isn't it?

Im showing the `fragment` on my `mainActivity` throughout this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
BlankFragment frag = null;
FragmentManager manager = null;
FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frag = new BlankFragment();
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, frag, "TesteFragment");

    transaction.commit();

}
```

Here the colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item name="blue" type="color">#357893</item>
<item name="bluish" type="color">#85B8CC</item>
<item name="bluish_dark" type="color">#0F5069</item>

</resources>
```

Comment: could you show your colors.xml ? Especially part with bluish_dark and bluish

Comment: Hey @Mago, i edited it and added the colors.xml!

Answer (score 0):

try editing your colors.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="blue">#357893</color>
<color name="bluish">#85B8CC</color>
<color name="bluish_dark">#0F5069</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Hey @Mago, thanks for the answer, i changed it but still it shows the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file which contains the correct XML for colors, in your case:

```
<resources>
<color name="blue" type="color">#357893</item>
<color name="bluish" type="color">#85B8CC</item>
<color name="bluish_dark" type="color">#0F5069</item>
</resources>
```

This *silly* error could be avoided by using an IDE, which will error out when it is not defined properly. Sorry that I am saying silly here, but we all have our derps, don't feel bad about it :P

Comment: Hey @codequestioneer, thanks for the answer! I changed it and got where i made a mistake but it still return the same as before. =/

Comment: @MathLoures You might want to clean your project then, because the color should apply if you define the colors like I stated. It is maybe obvious, but are you sure you have the file located in the res/values folder?